# What do the icons under the pilot's star rating stand for?

Tags: achtung-spitfire

In the campaign mode of "Achtung! Spitfire" Pilots can have several icons right beneath their star rating:

[image: Achtung! Spitfire Group info screen]

The 5+ icon indicates that the pilot has scored at least 5 kills. What do the other icons stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keen eyes is used in the campaign game. It improves "First spot".  "First spot" means you spot the enemy number and position first. Then you can determine whether you want to  engage your squad  or run depending on the situation -Very useful.

A pilot with Hero rating improves the initiative (morale) of other squad members.   Green pilots are less  likely to abort mission.  Also improved initiative is very important because it determines who moves and shoots first.  High initiative pilots move last (simulates that a veteran pilot moves after a  Green one) and then shoot first.

Crack shot also make more "critical hits (e.g. engine) The damage model is more extensive than it seems and not fully explained in manual.

Yes...Pilot qualities do improve in the campaign game.

Great game_ Have  owned since Both Achtung  and the first  "Over the Reich" were released by BigTime software.  I have  running on Vista laptop...It may be helpful to know that Both games were based on a very detailed wargames of the same name by J.D. Webster.  Both games are very detailed "under the hood" and this is not obvious by the look of the games or the manual supplied.  ...Needs a good FAQ for both

Answer (score -2):

The eye is keen eyes, I can only guess what it helps with.

The s is hero, again I have no idea. Maybe they die harder because they are heroic.

The cross hair is crack shot. It has to increase the percentage on hitting targets.

I've seen the  5+ flying ace on a pilot with less than 5 kills, I figure it improves some dynamic. Maybe it helps cause more damage.

The gifted flyer green airplane makes the pilot able to maneuver more efficiently.

I'm just guessing mostly, but I would love to find out too.